# One Gremlin query to get all connected vertices for multiple vertices

Tags: java, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

may I get some help from improving our query?

So the idea is that we have many connected sub-graphs, and each vertex has an unique id. Now we know some of ids, and we want to get all of the connected vertices in one query.

For example, we have **a -> b <- c -> d**, and **e -> f <- g**. Now the input is **{b, e}**, and the result we want is **{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}**. Because, {a, c, d} is connected to b and {f, g} is connected to e.

Current I’m using a very dumb query like

```
g.V("b").emit().repeat(both().simplePath()).aggregate("connected")
 .V("e").emit().repeat(both().simplePath()).aggregate("connected")
 .select("connected").unfold().dedup()
```

which might work sometimes, but when (if) all the vertices are already connected to each other, I will run into MemoryLimitExceededException

Answer (score 0):

The Gremlin Recipes include a connected components recipe but may not be appropriate for very large graphs. Please take a look at [1].

[1] https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#connected-components